# My prefix is good at something, my infix is some type of bar, my suffix conveys something

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is good at something
>
> My infix is some type of bar
>
> My suffix conveys something

Hint:

> It's another word for solution, the final result.

Comment: This seems a bit bare. A hint, or an extra line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Product

My prefix is good at something

> **Pro** - as mentioned by El-Guest

My infix is some type of bar

> **Rod** - which is a synonym for bar

My suffix conveys something

> **Duct** - a tube or passageway used to convey air, water, cables, etc.

Hint

> **Product** is another word for result or solution

Comment: Correct! How did you know? You guys are way too fast!

Answer (score 3):

Could this be a

> PROTHESIS?

My prefix is good at something

> A PRO is good at something.

My infix is some type of bar

> Maybe this is a T-bar as in skiing.

My suffix conveys something

> A THESIS will convey a message.

Comment: Nope! But nice one! Wow.